# Selected item list in html optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of buttons on my page. I'm trying to make a feature so that when you click a button it becomes selected (I will change its color), and the last clicked button will come back to normal.

The only idea that I could come up for this (based on my newbish skills) is to make a javascript function, which will iterate through all the buttons from the page, and change the color for each of them to the default color, then change color for the clicked button.

This way doesn't seem optimum, as I iterate through the entire list of buttons when I only need to change two. How can I do it in a better way?

I'm not looking for code, just an idea.

Comment: Can you maintain a list of which buttons are clicked? Then you have a pre-selected list rather than iterating through the entire button set.

Comment: Can I do that in javascript? I only know how to do it in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery.

```
$('.btn').on("click", function() { 
       $('.active').removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Give all the buttons you want this functionality the "btn" css class and then make another css class called active.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a class to changed button

```
$('#someid').addClass('someclass');
```

and then check if the button has class

```
$('#someid').hasClass(className);
```

**UPD**

this should work as well

```
$('.classForAllButtons').css(/*css here*/);
$('clicked element').css(/*css here*/);
```

this will add style to all buttons and then immediately add css to the clicked button